# Xero API - How to specify page size in the pagination

Tags: pagination, paging, xero-api

According to the docs:

https://developer.xero.com/documentation/api/requests-and-responses

> If there are 100 records in the response you will need to check if
>   there is any more data by fetching the next page e.g ?page=2 and
>   continuing this process until no more results are returned. **It is not**
>   **possible to specify the page size**.

Currently I am paging the records on my end i.e. showing 10 records per page but always requesting all invoices. Why are they forcing 100 items per page? My system might be designed to request only 10 records per page and I still need to fetch minimum 100.

My question is - is there any hidden gem that I can utilise in order to decrease the records page size? And if there isn't - are they planing to change that? (I am pointing this question to their community people here :) )

EDIT:

I read somewhere that this is a convention between REST API devs. Can someone explain why is that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to specify the page size on the Xero API.
Generally we would recommend that you build up a read store on your end and use the if-modified-since header to keep it up to date rather than requesting all the invoices every time you want to load them.

I'm not 100% sure why it's a convention on REST APIs to not allow the page size to be specified, but based on what I know of our API it's likely to be there to discourage people from mapping their application logic to the API and to give the API devs more control over variables that can affect performance.